# Anagram finder program in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, finder, anagram

I need to code an program that finds anagrams of words. When the program starts, it asks the user to enter words into a 'dictionary' which will be searched later on for anagrams of words which again the user will input.

I have stored all the words of the dictionary in a vector called `oldDict`. The characters in each word are then arranged alphabetically and the new character-sorted words are stored in a vector called `newDict`, to preserve the original words in `oldDict`.

The user then enters a word for which anagram(s) must be found in the dictionary. as soon as the word is entered, i again tried to sort the characters of the word alphabetically, in order to then compare it to each element in `newDict` and find anagrams in this manner.

Below is my code:

```
ifndef ANAGRAM_H
#define ANAGRAM_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector <string> oldDict;
vector <string> newDict;
int dictSize = 0;

void readDict(void){    // Allows the user to input all the words they would like to     have in the anagram dictionary.
    cout<< "Please enter the number of dictionary entries you wish to create\n";
    cin >> dictSize;
    string word = "";
    cout << "Please enter the dictionary entries, 1 by 1, pushing <enter> after each entry.\n";
    for(int i = 0; i <dictSize; i++){
        cin >> word;
        oldDict.push_back(word);
    }
    newDict = oldDict;
}   

void sortChars(void){   //sorts the letters in each word of the 'dictionary' so that the     letters are in alphabetical order.
    for(int i = 0; i < dictSize; i++){
        std::sort(newDict[i].begin(), newDict[i].end());    
    }
}

void getWords(void){
    int num = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the number of words for which you would like to find anagrams     of:\n";
    cin >> num;
    string word = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i ++){
        cout << "Please enter a word:\n";
        cin>>word;
        std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());    
        for(int i = 0; i < dictSize; i++){
            string word2 = newDict[i];
            bool isAn = isAnagram(word, word2);
            if(isAn == true){
                cout << oldDict[i];
            } else{
            }
        }
    }
}

bool isAnagram(string word1, string word2){

    if(word1.compare(word2) ==0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
}

void menu(void){
    readDict();
    sortChars();
    getWords();
}
#endif
```

The process starts in the `order()` function at the bottom of the code.

When trying to compile the code, i receive the following errors:

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
./anagram.h: In function ‘void sortChars()’:
./anagram.h:25:3: error: ‘sort’ is not a member of ‘std’
   std::sort(newDict[i].begin(), newDict[i].end()); 
   ^
./anagram.h: In function ‘void getWords()’:
./anagram.h:37:4: error: ‘sort’ is not a member of ‘std’
    std::sort(word.begin(), word.end()); 
    ^
./anagram.h:40:38: error: ‘isAnagram’ was not declared in this scope
     bool isAn = isAnagram(word, word2);
```

Could someone please help me solve those errors? I really dont understand while 'isAnagram' is giving an error, and also if someone could please explain what 'std::' does and why those two lines of code are creating errors?

Thanks very much

Comment: `#include <algorithm>` and declared functions before use

Comment: Typo-based issue: unlikely to be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

`‘sort’ is not a member of ‘std’` Add `#include <algorithm>`

`‘isAnagram’ was not declared in this scope` Declare the function before its first use.

Moreover implementation of isAnagram doesn't look correct. You can not plain compare strings. You should sort the strings before comparing them.

```
bool isAnagram(string word1, string word2){
    std::sort(word1.begin(), word1.end()); // added
    std::sort(word2.begin(), word2.end()); // added
    if(word1.compare(word2) ==0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm having trouble understanding what you mean when you say 'declare the function before its first use'? Is it incorrect how i have declared a boolean variable 'isAn' and immediately assigned to it a boolean value, which will be returned by the isAnagram function?

Comment: Oh nevermind, i keep forgetting that the order of functions matters in C++. Thanks very much for all your help :)

Comment: In case you want to understand `declaration vs definition in C and C++`, I would suggest googling highlighted term and go through a few links.